# js function behaves differently depending on how it is called

Tags: javascript, html, select, onclick, onchange

I'm trying to make it so that changing the selected option of a select tag will submit the form the same as a button would, I have:

```
function form_search()
{
    document.forms['myform'].process.value = 'search';
    document.forms['myform'].submit();
}
```

included from just before the `/body` tag in the html file including:

```
<select name="attribute" form="myform" onchange="form_search();">
    <option value="op1">op1</option>
    <option value="op2">op2</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="process">

<button onclick="form_search();">button</button>
```

When I hit the button everything works as I would expect. However when I change the option associated with the select tag, according to firebug it seems to hit both the lines in the js function but the form doesn't seem to submit. Im thinking there is an error being triggered on the `document.forms['myform'].submit();` line of the js function in this case.

Any ideas what is going on? Surely two calls to a function with no args should behave the same?

Comment: "Im thinking there is an error" — What does the JavaScript error console say?

Comment: could you also include the `form` we are talking about here.

Comment: did not even know there was an error console, thanks! just for the record it says "TypeError: document.forms.myform.submit is not a function" so the accepted answer provides a reason why the form was submitting anyway, thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `document.forms['myform'].submit();` does error, then the most likely reason is that there is something inside the form named `submit` which is overwriting the `submit` method of the form in the DOM. There is no sign of this in the code you have shared with us though.

Given that:

Changing the select will run the JS. The first line will run. The second line will error and that is the end of it.

Clicking the button will run the JS. The first line will run. The second line will error. The normal behaviour of the button will continue and it will submit the form (using the standard HTML for form submission instead of the JS).